# shutil.move() shows an error even the path is correct

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

Here is my code

```
shutil.move('D:\folder1\2016000000242300_65500000007016_11_2.png','D:\folder2\discarded')
```

When I run this code I see the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\folder1\x816000000242300_65500000007016_11_2.png'

It is so strange to see x8 after `folder1\`. When I use one more backslash after `folder1` it works. I do not understand what causes this and how to solve. I create the full path by using os.path.join().
Here is how I do it:

```
def clean_Data(inputDir, outDir)
    pathnamein = os.path.join(inputDir, fname)
    pathnameout = os.path.join(outDir, fname)
    shutil.move(pathnamein, pathnameout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amadan is completely correct about the cause of your problem.

Rather than manually inserting the backslashes, I'm recommend using the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library to wrap the paths since you are using Python 3.

```
import shutil
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath    
src = PureWindowsPath('D:\folder1\2016000000242300_65500000007016_11_2.png')
dst = PureWindowsPath('D:\folder2\discarded')

shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Or, based on your comments, you can do

```
src = PureWindowsPath(inputDir) / PureWindowsPath(fname)
dst = PureWindowsPath(outDir) / PureWindowsPath(fname)
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

A more platform independent solution might be

```
from pathlib import Path
src = Path(inputDir) / Path(fname)
dst = Path(outDir) / Path(fname)
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

This way the library automatically infers the necessary OS specific details of your filesystem and adjust the slashes accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But when I try Path(inputDir) / Path(fname) with explicit inputDir and fname, I see the strange x8 again. I think the problem is not with the assigned path name but with the slashes. They cause the problem @Adaman mentioned. I have to find a solution for this. When I use Path(inputDir) or PureWindowsPath(inputDir) backslashes are replaced with forward slashes and I see those strange changes in path names.

Comment: @DiegoEslava I did not say the issue is with the assigned path name. It is with how the system interprets backslash, as noted by @Amadan and as I have acknowledged at the top of my answer. When **printing**, the system will interpret `\nnn`  as a special character (in this case "\20" becomes "\x8"), which is why you are seeing a different string printed out. I don't use Windows but I believe pathlib should be able to handle the path properly even if it is not printed out as the exact raw string. If possible let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Actually I tried but it did not work. This really surprised me. I found a solution to change the pathnamein to a raw string (rawpath = "%r"%pathnamein). Now I can get the directory properly. I am so close to reach to the final result. Thanks a lot for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

In Python string literals, backslash is called an escape character, since it "escapes" the following character or several, giving them special meaning, or stripping special meaning from them.

In particular, `\nnn` is a way to insert a character by its ASCII code, with `nnn` being an octal number. There are related forms, like `\xnn`, where `nn` is hexadecimal. In your case, `\201` is equivalent to `\x81`, which is equivalent to the ASCII character at decimal position 129.

`\\` is another escape sequence, where the escape character escapes itself, stripping it of special significance. This is the way to include an actual backslash into the string. When you say "...\2016..."`, Python sees "character #129, then a six"; when you say "...\\2016..."`, Python sees "a backslash, two, zero, one, six".

Comment: I understand. But I cannot find a solution. The file path is created automatically and I cannot change it manually.

Comment: You say "I create the full path by using os.path.join()". You also say "Here is my code". And yet there is no `os.path.join` in your code. I can't help you further unless you actually tell the truth :) Meaning, the actual relevant code that leads  to the error, including how the string is created.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. Here is the original code
def clean_Data(inputDir, outDir)
       pathnamein = os.path.join(inputDir, fname)
       pathnameout = os.path.join(outDir, fname)
       shutil.move(pathnamein, pathnameout)
I was using the codes in the question to try shutil.move().

Comment: No worries. However, I can't see how this code can produce the above issue. This code should work. The code in your OP should not, for the reasons I described, but I can't see any error in this one.